How to easily standardise pandas dataframe
I have below pandas dataframe
import pandas as pd
dat = pd.DataFrame({'AA': [1, 2], 'BB': [3,4]})

I am looking for a direct way to standardise each column like in SAS we have PROC STDIZE.
Is there any direct method available with pandas?

This question is similar to: Normalize columns of a dataframe. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You could try dat_norm = (dat - dat.mean())/dat.std()
